# Drupal: my back-end edit node page jumps up when I click "save"

Tags: drupal

Using [Drupal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drupal): When I click on button "Save" to save the changes to a page, the top of the back-end is immediately removed, and all the content is shifted up for some reason..

How can I fix this?

Comment: Does the form get posted/submitted at all or does the 'remove/shift' take place immediately?

Comment: the form is posted/submitted. It is actually something remaining there for few seconds. By the way, if I'm using FUpload module, which requires several steps to upload the images, the page remains shifted. Everything works perfectly.

Comment: Hmm, sounds weird - is it shifted as in 'page scrolled upwards' or 'top content disappears completely'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like some JavaScript code going haywire, attaching a handler to the form submit while it shouldn't. You should try to use the form with JavaScript disabled in the browser - if the behavior does not occur then, you need to check which JavaScript code is responsible for it. (Possibly some sloppy code from a contributed module - you can also turn off all contributed modules to see if this changes the behavior - if it does, turn them back on one by one to find the offender.)